# How to ignore a column when update in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a book table and status column (Bit type) on it, I have 3 situations when editing my book info form.

1. if book available status field = true,
2. if book not available status field = false,
3. if only editing books info except status field, it should ignore the status column on MySQL table as it is

So for the 3rd situation, I have to ignore the status column if there is no value set, Is there any way I can do? please help me out

This is my update query

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE books SET book_title = :title, file_type = :file_type, status = :status WHERE id = :id');

    $this->db->bind(':title', $data['title']);
    $this->db->bind(':file_type', $data['file_type']);
    $this->db->bind(':status', $data['availability']);
    $this->db->bind(':id', $data['id']);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"it should ignore the status column"_? If you don't want to update it, don't put `status = :status` in your query

Comment: yes but if there is a value set im using the same query update it, that's the problem

Comment: Then you can't use the same query, as easy as that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql's [`ifnull()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) and pass null for status if you don't want to update it.  The idea being that if you pass null, you just leave the value as it is...

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE books 
                  SET book_title = :title, file_type = :file_type,
                      status = ifnull(:status,status) 
                  WHERE id = :id');

$this->db->bind(':title', $data['title']);
$this->db->bind(':file_type', $data['file_type']);
if () { // You want to set the value
    $this->db->bind(':status', $data['availability']);
}
else  { // leave value as is
    $this->db->bind(':status', null);
}
$this->db->bind(':id', $data['id']);
```

You will need to complete the `if()` bit to determine how you want this logic to happen.

Comment: for the status dropdown manu i have only 2 options that true or false, however either one option will set the value, so how i can check in if condtion? if isset method wont work in my case. so do i need to add anothor value in my dropdown menu to check?

Comment: You could assume that this value in the dropdown is what the user wants and always update it (meaning the question isn't really needed).  You could have a dropdown value which is 'Ignore' and this would just leave the value as it was.  You could have an option on your screen which says which bits of the data you want updating.

Comment: Thanks mate ill try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(isset($data['status'])) {
  $status = ', status = :status';
}

$this->db->query("UPDATE books SET book_title = :title, file_type = :file_type $status WHERE id = :id");

$this->db->bind(':title', $data['title']);
$this->db->bind(':file_type', $data['file_type']);
if(isset($data['status'])) {
  $this->db->bind(':status', $data['availability']);
}
$this->db->bind(':id', $data['id']);
```

Just check for `$data['status']` if its not empty then concatenate it into your query.

Comment: did it help, my mate?

Comment: in a dropdown menu only i am getting status value true or false, in this case how i assign it is not set?

Comment: @Looper drop down field?

Comment: sorry dropdown menu, I can only select available or not available, so however it is setting the value

Comment: If your dropdown menu only allows the values `available` and `not available` how can you tell if the user was setting the status or just editing the book details?

Comment: yah thats correct, so ill add another option for it, thank you mate